# Cardan (or Tait-Bryan) angles z-x-y and rotation matrix - Proof

Tags: matrices, education, rotations, classical-mechanics, angle

I'm trying to get the following rotation matrix (cardan angle sequence z-x-y):

[image]

To do that, I multiplied the three elementary rotation matrices $R_zR_xR_y$, but the result is different:

[image]

Can you tell me how can I reach my goal please?

Thank you so much.

Comment: It looks as if you are doing the component-wise product instead of the matrix product.  [WolframAlpha result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7Bcos(gamma),-sin(gamma),0%7D,%7Bsin(gamma),cos(gamma),0%7D,%7B0,0,1%7D%7D+%7B%7B1,0,0%7D,%7B0,cos(alpha),-sin(alpha)%7D,%7B0,sin(alpha),cos(alpha)%7D%7D+%7B%7Bcos(beta),0,sin(beta)%7D,%7B0,1,0%7D,%7B-sin(beta),0,cos(beta)%7D%7D)

Comment: Hello @user10354138, can you explain with a formula your comment please?

Comment: See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices))

Comment: Thank you very much @user10354138